# Parsing a Custom DateTime string

Tags: c#, datetime

I am attempting to parse a string into a DateTime, using the ParseExact() method.

```
string input = "Wednesday, March 4, 2015 - 9:00 AM PST";
string format = @"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy - h:mm tt \P\S\T";
```

Parsing this input with this format fails, but I can't see why it is wrong.

If I do

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(format));
```

Then I get an output in the same format as the above input. So this would indicate that the format is indeed correct.

Appreciate your thoughts - Saqib

Comment: parses fine for me using `\\P\\S\\T`

Comment: Why are you using `\\` before P, S and T? It does not compile when backslash is used. If backslash is removed it all works fine

Comment: @dotnetom - OP uses `@"..." so it compile ok, "\" will be preserved and used by `ParseExact` as "treat next character explicitly". As my answer show "it all works fine" as long as your language/country is "en-US" (or "en-" with formatting options close to the "en-US"), for other places it will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current locale issue (or more specifically day of week/month translation):

```
var ok = DateTime.ParseExact(
     "Wednesday, March 4, 2015 - 9:00 AM PST", "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy - h:mm tt PST",
      new CultureInfo("en-us"))
var failed = DateTime.ParseExact(
     "Wednesday, March 4, 2015 - 9:00 AM PST", "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy - h:mm tt PST",
      new CultureInfo("de-de"))
```

Comment: +1, but "or more specifically day of week/month translation" is not the only potential problem "h:mm" will expect a culture-specific TimeSeparator, which may be something other than colon.  The OP should specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: @Joe - good point (as well as `tt` is different too...) - explicitly specifying correct (possibly Invariant) culture is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your example code won't compile, as the escape char '\' itself needs to be escaped. Or, you can prefix the format string with a '@' to make it literal.

The following works;

```
string input = "Wednesday, March 4, 2015 - 9:00 AM PST";
string format = @"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy - h:mm tt \P\S\T";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

However, you need to be aware that a DateTime instance contains no timezone information, so the result will be assumed to be a local time (which is why I explicitly state that in the ParseExact call), and that 'PST' is not recognised as a timezone anyway, even were you to use a DateTimeOffset type (which does contain TimeZone details)